# How Can I enable DirectPlay without Admin Rights?

Tags: command-line, non-admin

I've been trying to get GTA SA to work but apparently I need to enable DirectPlay, how can I do that without Admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

DirectPlay is a Windows feature that was deprecated in newer Windows versions.
By newer I mean dating from about the last decade.

Today this is a Windows feature that needs to be enabled through
*Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off*.

As only an Administrator may install Windows features, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This will enable directplay from the command line

DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:LegacyComponents

DISM /online /enable-feature /featurename:DirectPlay